# Problem with SQL and WHERE and INSERT INTO in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause, sql-insert

I am trying to transfer values from Tab01 to Tab02, under the condition that these values do not already exist in Tab02. The tables have different number of columns which is why I can't use Insert Into * but I have to name the individual columns. My SQL statement is:

```
strsql = "INSERT INTO Tab02 (col01,col02,col04,col09)" & _
"SELECT Tab01.col01,Tab01.col02,Tab01.col04,Tab01.col09" & _
" FROM Tab01" & _
" WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col01 From Tab01)"
```

Without **WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col01 From Tab01)** in the end all works, but with the condition nothing happens.

What should be the correct syntax for this? So transfer/copy the mentioned values from the Tab01 in Tab02 if (e.g. as reference) the value Tab01.col01 does not already exist in Tab02.col02 (please exactly, with the appropriate special characters...because sql forgives as well known no still so tiny error!) thanks!

Comment: Maybe: FROM Tabl01 WHERE NOT col01 IN (SELECT col01 FROM Tab02)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IN` or a correlated subquery:

```
INSERT INTO Tab02 (col01, col02, col04, col09)
    SELECT Tab01.col01, Tab01.col02, Tab01.col04, Tab01.col09
    FROM Tab01
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Tab01
                      WHERE Tab01.col01 = Tab02.col01
                     );
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get an input field where is asked for the field content!

Comment: @Jasco . . . That would suggest that one of the columns you are referencing are not really columns.  Check your spelling.